# Facebook Javascript API not returning email on subdomain

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook connect via their javsacript api to allow users to login to our site.

I'm just trying to return name and email.

All is fine on my dev box and our staging environment, but not on live. Live returns name, but not email...

dev and staging are on subdomains or our company domain. And live is on a subdomain of our clients domain.

If I examine the headers after the request to FB on live, a message comes back:

"message":"The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'email' permission."

The weird thing is that email is a permission given to apps by default.

My feeling is that the client top level domain might also have an FB app and something is clashing.

Any ideas?

thanks!

EDIT:
I am asking for email in the request, here's some code

```
$FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
                            angular.element('.user-data-fields input[name=name]').val(response.name);
                            angular.element('.user-data-fields input[name=email]').val(response.email);
                        });
```

and here is the request to FB

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=BIGOLDACCESSTOKENGOESHERE&callback=FB.__globalCallbacks.f33b1b77a8&debug=all&fields=name,email&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey

and the response from FB:

```
"message":"The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'email' permission."
```

thanks :)

Comment: Are you asking for the email field also?

Comment: _“The weird thing is that email is a permission given to apps by default”_ – no, it is of course not. You have to ask the user for it via the login dialog, and the user then has to grant it to your app. You are likely confusing this with which permissions need _review_ by Facebook (`email` is one of the three basic ones which don’t.)

Comment: Hey, Yup I sure am asking for email - hence it works on dev and staging, here's a snippet of my code

Comment: Hey, Yup I sure am asking for email - it works on dev and staging, here's a snippet of my code

$FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
       angular.element('.user-data-fields input[name=name]').val(response.name);
       angular.element('.user-data-fields input[name=email]').val(response.email);
      });


and here is the request to FB

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=BIGOLDACCESSTOKENGOESHERE&callback=FB.__globalCallbacks.f33b1b77a8&debug=all&fields=name,email&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey

thanks :)